# How to define one to many relationship in django

Tags: python, django

I have a condition that has one to many relationship scenarios because I will have multiple projects inside one account.

models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

class Project(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

how can I manage this scenario, currently I'm getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "project_account_id_7d9b231b" already exists
```

Comment: Make `Account` a subclass of `User` and make `account` a FK to `Account`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```